# List the set of points of discontinuity of piecewise function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

List the set of points of discontinuity of $f:(0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$, defined by

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x-[x]\text{ if [x] is even}\\1-x+[x]\text{ if [x] is odd}\end{cases}$$

Comment: What have you already tried? When you wrote the question, you left out that important information as well as another key piece of info: where did you encounter the question (what class, what textbook)? Including these things is important for people to give helpful answers.

Comment: I found it here: http://www.nbhm.dae.gov.in/docs/msc12.pdf

Comment: I recommend calculating by hand what $f(x)$ is on the interval $[0,4]$ and looking for a pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We see $$x\in(0,1), \text{floor}(x)=0 ~~~~~\text{so}~~~f(x)=x$$ $$x\in[1,2), \text{floor}(x)=1 ~~~~~\text{so}~~~f(x)=2-x$$ $$x\in[2,3), \text{floor}(x)=2 ~~~~~\text{so}~~~f(x)=x-2\\\ .\\\ .\\\ .$$ It seems the function is continuous.

[image]

Comment: It should be more rigorous

Comment: @user80173: What points are you stuck in? Isn't the picture clear? Tell me.

Comment: Nice work, Babak! Your handiwork is illustrating the site very nicely ;-)

Comment: @amWhy: thanks for saying so. but i didn't notice if the OP got the solution? i didn't know.

Comment: I think, yes, most likely, given the $\checkmark$ ;-).  I like you new avatar!!

Comment: @BabakS. Yes. I've got it. Thanks so much.